# Copy rows and change 1 value?

Tags: sql

How would I copy entire rows within a table and change one value?

```
 insert into user (
     user_id,account_id,user_type_cd,name,e_mail_addr,
     login_failure_cnt,admin_user,primary_user
 )
 select * from pnet_user where account_id='1'
```

But now I want to change 1 to 2 on the inserted entries. 
But now I want to change 1 to 3 on the inserted entries. 
But now I want to change 1 to .... on the inserted entries. 
But now I want to change 1 to 1000 on the inserted entries.

It will copy and write down 1000 times (only changing id ).

Comment: This is a SQL and/or PHP question. That isn't even a WordPress table you are dealing with. Perhaps ask to have it moved to [so]

Comment: actually i don't understand which value do you want to change but, if you mean `account_id` on where clause you can use `BETWEEN 1 AND 1000` statement

Comment: Which column are you wanting to change?  Stop using * and replace with the values for each column you want.

Answer (score 21):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're asking.  If you want to copy the records where Account_ID = 1 into new rows and change Account_ID to 2 (or whatever number), this should work for you:

```
insert into user (user_id,account_id,user_type_cd,name,e_mail_addr,
     login_failure_cnt,admin_user,primary_user)
select user_id,2,user_type_cd,name,e_mail_addr,
     login_failure_cnt,admin_user,primary_user 
from pnet_user where account_id='1'
```

Basically, replace Account_ID with the value 2.  If Account_ID is a varchar, use single quotes around it instead.

Comment: +1 I believe you're correct, and if not, the OP can modify from here to suit their needs.

Comment: so obvious, yet I didn't think of it!